# Installing Ansible via Pip on Windows 7. Getting ValueError

Tags: python, windows, pip, ansible

Firstly some basic details:

OS: Windows 7 Home x64

Relevant libraries installed:

.NET Framework 4.0, Windows SDK (in order to have visual c++ 2010 compiler)

Python: 3.4 (tried 32 and 64 bit, same issue)

Pip: 6.0.8

I'm trying to install Ansible (via command prompt) but I get the error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']

Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\<myname>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bxrpw5rf\\cffi\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\myname>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z1_s87va-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bxrpw5rf\cffi
```

So far my own googling hasn't turned up anything that I can distinguish as a solution relevant to this particular case. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are on you own here, because there is no support for Python 3 in Ansible yet, neither for Windows as control machine.

[Control Machine Requirements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements):

> Currently Ansible can be run from any machine with Python 2.6 or 2.7 installed (Windows isn’t supported for the control machine).
>
> **Note** Python 3 is a slightly different language than Python 2 and some Python programs (including Ansible) are not switching over yet.

There are some success stories with Ansible under `Cygwin` on Windows.